# Does after insert trigger fire on update?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to understand what is causing this deadlock.
The update command in the first process is the result of the trigger from the insert command. So I am trying to understand if the insert trigger fire on update?

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process1fb169468" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process1fb169468" taskpriority="0" logused="2044" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057598307401728 (c73677424644)" waittime="61674" ownerId="34455794" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-07-11T23:24:01.387" XDES="0x56bee18e0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="6" kpid="9800" status="suspended" spid="94" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-07-11T23:24:01.387" lastbatchcompleted="2022-07-11T23:24:01.387" lastattention="2022-07-11T22:02:36.350" clientapp="Vizion WMS" hostname="AGROXAWORK02" hostpid="10484" loginname="vizion" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="34455794" currentdb="5" currentdbname="WMSData" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671219744" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="WMSData.dbo.UpdateDes" line="5" stmtstart="154" stmtend="298" sqlhandle="0x030005000caa6e4b5b56dd0089a6000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update inventory set designation = 'FROZEN' where designation &lt;&gt; 'FROZEN    </frame>
    <frame procname="WMSData.dbo.PostReceipt" line="101" stmtstart="7960" stmtend="10026" sqlhandle="0x0300050071b68341909a680037ae000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
INSERT INTO [wmsdata].[dbo].[Inventory]
            ([Customer],[Product],[Row],[Rack],[Slot],[Pallets],[Cases],[Net],[ProductDate],[ReceiverNumber],[LotNumber],[ReceiveDate],[StorThru],[Status],[PalletNumber],[CustomerPallet],[StartTime],[StopTime],[BornOnDate],[EnteredBy],[ImportOrManual],[FullPalletQty],[PalletQtyReceived],[CustomerReference],lpnumber,fcgpallet,designation,mark,invoptional1,invoptional2,invoptional3,invoptional4,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,rsrate)
             select [Customer],[Product],[Row],[Rack],[Slot],[Pallets],[Cases],[Net],[ProductDate],[Receiver],[LotNumber],convert(char(12),getdate(),101) as [ReceiveDate],[StorThru],[Status],[PalletNumber],[CustomerPallet],[StartTime],[StopTime],convert(char(12),getdate(),101) as [BornOnDate],[EnteredBy],[ImportOrManual],[FullPalletQty],cases as [PalletQtyReceived], @r, lpnumber, fcgpallet,designation,mark,invoptional1,invoptional2,invoptional3,invoptional4,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,rsrate
             from [wmsdata].[dbo].receipts  with (nolock) where palletnum    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0100050098f50238607f6f0b0500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
exec dbo.postreceipt '149496','RDAY'    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
exec dbo.postreceipt '149496','RDAY'   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process46811bc28" taskpriority="0" logused="22480" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057598307401728 (771c8a402149)" waittime="4364" ownerId="34439550" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-07-11T23:22:34.483" XDES="0x5a043d770" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="10752" status="suspended" spid="59" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-07-11T23:22:34.497" lastbatchcompleted="2022-07-11T23:22:33.330" lastattention="2022-07-11T23:17:04.210" clientapp="Vizion WMS" hostname="AGROXAWORK02" hostpid="12144" loginname="vizion" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="34439550" currentdb="5" currentdbname="WMSData" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="WMSData.dbo.PostShipment" line="161" stmtstart="16962" stmtend="17036" sqlhandle="0x0300050069a66001dd5e640021ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
delete from inventory where cases &lt;=    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x01000500f2278100b05d31790100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
exec Postshipment '257208', 'JJOHNSON'    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
exec Postshipment '257208', 'JJOHNSON'   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <keylock hobtid="72057598307401728" dbid="5" objectname="WMSData.dbo.Inventory" indexname="PK_Inventory" id="lock4e671e880" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057598307401728">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process46811bc28" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process1fb169468" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
  <keylock hobtid="72057598307401728" dbid="5" objectname="WMSData.dbo.Inventory" indexname="PK_Inventory" id="lock52ec3d280" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057598307401728">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process1fb169468" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process46811bc28" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: _Does after insert trigger fire on update?_ Not directly. `from [wmsdata].[dbo].receipts  with (nolock) ` You should be worried - don't splatter your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) without understanding the consequences.

Comment: An `AFTER INSERT` trigger will not fire, but in your call stack you have an `INSERT INTO [wmsdata].[dbo].[Inventory]` which is firing the trigger, which then does an `update inventory`. To properly diagnose a deadlock, we need at a minimum: the full XDL graph (you have already give us that), the relevant tables *and indexes* definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: Seconding Charlieface, but from a quick scan it looks like the logic here is `insert inventory` from the first process (ok), then `delete inventory` coming from a second process (waiting for the first process to commit), followed by the triggered `update inventory` in the first process, which seems likely to affect a lot of rows (the predicate is an inequality), which is waiting on the `delete` in the second process. So each process is waiting on the other.